# Get zeros when read flash STM32F405

Tags: stm32, linux, st

G'evening!
I'm working with a board on STM32F405RTG6 (unfortunately, I can't post a photo of the board). When I try `st-flash read filename.bin 0x08000000 0x000FFFFF` to read flash and `hexdump -C filename.bin | less` I get lots of similar "blocks":

```
00006000  80 00 00 00 03 00 03 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00006010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00006780  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00006790  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
```

The RDP byte is set (I don't know if it is at level 2). I'm using linux and console instead of IDE.

The question is: why the output looks like that? Is it because the RDP byte is set of is it because there's something wrong with the code?

P.S. I haven't programmed this MCU so I don't know about the code. First time using the same method I got digit combinations blocks insead of zeroes which couldn't be translated into ASCII. Second time I got characters instead of zeroes. They were letters and "+", "\" and so on but they didn't make any sense!

Comment: Perhaps you have data with zeroes in your program. How would we know what you have programmed in your MCU. I guess you won't show source code or original programmed binary either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.